# How Do I Use /scoreboard To Change Clone or Tp Coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't really know how to explain this, but here goes. I'm working on a map. I have a huge 20x1x200 area, and I'm cloning it into a 20x1x20 area. The command goes a little like this:

> /clone 12 104 -55 14 124 -91 46 121 24

then

> /clone 12 104 -54 14 124 -90 46 121 24

then

> /clone 12 104 -53 14 124 -89 46 121 24

And so on. Is there someway to do this with a couple of Command blocks? I'm not really in the mood to paste this into 250 command blocks.

Hope you guys understand, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Why are you cloning over the area you just cloned in a previous command, just one block removed?  If you're running all of these commands in the same command block chain, only the last one will matter.  Also, the scoreboard alone won't help here.  You're assuming the solution when you should be focusing on the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to focus on this in detail. I'm trying to recreate a game like flappy bird in minecraft, where the background move as you went along. I thought if I made a big model, and then used /clone so it could slowly be moved, it might work. If you need any more info to solve this problem please let me know

Comment: @user148180 No, I think this Isn't possible. What you could do is use relative coords and Command block cloning!

Comment: Err, I'm confused lel

Answer (score 1):

This is both possible and a late answer.

I don't know too much about it, but I believe you can use `/execute`. This will run the command from the perspective of an entity, so the relative coordinates will be centred on the entity, rather than the source from which the command was run.

Something like this should work, replacing the coordinates and removing the brackets: `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ clone (<x1> <y1> <z1>) (<x2> <y2> <z2>) (<x3> <y3> <z3>)`

So, for the final set of coordinates (x3,y3 and z3), you can use the `~` to clont relative to the player

Answer (score 0):

Your approach for cloning on a massive scale isn't the best idea. Instead, you should use structures. They can be completely relative to an entity. But going from the idea to move the whole scene, I think it would be better to keep the scene where it is and move the player instead.

So you simply have a command

```
/tp @p ~0.1 ~ ~
```

And another command to move a character on the scene (like the bird) and if you want to simulate Flappy Bird, you can now just tp the bird downwards.

```
/tp @e[tag=bird] ~0.1 ~-0.1 ~
```

To fly up you can use this command

```
execute @p[score_jump_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[tag=bird] ~ ~5 ~
```

The physics of this wouldn't be perfect, but you get the idea.